# Input Textbox does not update its value after updated state

Tags: reactjs

I am making this question short and strict forward, i have some input fields which are textboxs with defaultValue equal to state.someparameters such as

```
<input type='text' className='form-control' defaultValue={this.state.caseDetails.previous_case_number}/>

<p className='form-control-static'>{this.state.caseDetails.id}</p>
```

I initialize the state.caseDetails object with some String, which can be shown in the textbox correctly, However, after the ajax function which being called inside *componentDidMount*,
Even the state is updated, which can be seen in the react developer tools, the value being shown in the textboxs are still the original one, isn't react could automatically compare and update the view if setState method is called?

What are the problems that are causing this to occur? If i want to solve it, which the textbox will be showing the correct value after the setState, what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you copy the code of your component so I can build a jsbin to replicate this?

Comment: Sure, it maybe long and tedious, but i do really thank you for your help, updating in a moment.

Comment: it takes some time for me to trim down some codes, it exceeds 30000 characters which stackoverflow does not allow

Comment: Try to put it in a jsbin droplet so I can take a look

Comment: Here you are, sorry i took some time to figure it out: http://jsbin.com/deyuwihadu/edit?js

Comment: Uhm i guess i figured out the problem, is the ajax call that return error due to wrong json format. Sorry for wasting your time but i do upvote your answer.

Comment: Here you go http://jsbin.com/zupiho/edit?js,output
When you have defaultValue you are setting only the default, after that you need value attr because you have a controlled input https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: I'm glad you could fix it. 

Some advice about react: 
- Try to keep your components small
- Try to use stateless components if they just render divs and props
- Keep your state as small as possible
Make reusable, testable, and modular components